# Filter scroll view through search view

Tags: android, kotlin, filter, scrollview, searchview

I am new here. I need to ask something. I am building an android app in android stuido. I implemented 1 of my searchviews in an activity. In that activity, below the searchview is a scrollview with some imagebuttons in it. When I search in the searchview, I want that in the scrollview to be shown only the imagebuttons whose description or id is related to the search. How can I do that? And also I don't want the searchview to show me a list, but I want it to directly filter the results in the scrollview. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Get a reference to your `SearchView` widget in your activity's `onCreate()` method:

```
SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView);
```

Set an `OnQueryTextListener` on your `SearchView` to listen for text changes and perform the filtering logic:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        filterButtons(newText);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Implement the `filterButtons()` method to filter the `ImageButton` views in your `ScrollView` based on the search query:

```
private void filterButtons(String query) {
    for (int i = 0; i < scrollView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = scrollView.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ImageButton) {
            ImageButton button = (ImageButton) child;
            // Assuming each ImageButton has a tag containing its description or ID
            String description = button.getTag().toString();
            if (description.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
                button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, we iterate through each child of the ScrollView and check if it's an ImageButton. If it is, we retrieve its description or ID from its tag and compare it with the search query. If there's a match, we set its visibility to `View.VISIBLE`, otherwise, we set it to `View.GONE` to hide it.

Make sure you replace `R.id.searchView` with the actual ID of your SearchView widget, and scrollView with the ID of your ScrollView in the XML layout file.

With this implementation, as you type in the `SearchView`, the `ImageButton views` in the `ScrollView` will be dynamically shown or hidden based on the search query.

Comment: Does this solution solve your doubt/problem